# Is there a way to attach child list to particular view in ExpandableListView in android?

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview

I'm a new to android. Did some search to figure out how to attach `child views` to a particular element on parent/group. Please see this picture to see what I'm trying to achieve. [ExpandableListView](https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1JswFzhxwtQy9q0RhN2VNkXbqB_g43H064mbU4sUXVZs/edit?usp=sharing) . Is this possible with `ExpandableListView`?

I implemented the same with a `ListView` and a `child` `LinearLayout` in the `ListItem`. Is that a good solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See Vogella tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#expandablelistview

Comment: Did see that. In fact it was my first reference. :-). But that's not what I needed. I need an  expandablelistview  which have a footer for the groups. even if there is no child items, I need to show the footer to add child items. Is that possible?